# Angular 2 JSON Parsing not working

Tags: angular

I'm using Http.get to retrieve information via json format via angular 2.

Here's a service I'm using to get the json data which works:

```
getProd() {
    return this._http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/capital/tallinn')
        .map(res => res.json());   
}
```

Then in the component constructor I'm using:

```
this._etsyService.getProd().subscribe(product => {
        this.product = product;
    });
```

Then in the view template, if I specify:

```
{{ product | json }}
```

I get in the browser a raw json printout:

```
[ { "name": "Estonia", "topLevelDomain": [ ".ee" ], "alpha2Code": "EE", "alpha3Code": "EST", "callingCodes": [ "372" ], "capital": "Tallinn",
```

However, if I try to change {{ product, to {{ product.name }} for instance (with and without the pipe | json at the end, I get an error that it cannot read property 'name' of undefined?

I'm new to Angular, and I'm sure it's just a parsing issue I'm coming up with. I've tried a ton of combinations.

Help?

Comment: When template render, `product.name` is undefined. You using pipe `| json` to convert it to `JSON` format, if not it will raise your error. Just use pipe `| json` or place `*ngIf="product"` directive will solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not a single object, it's an array.

In your component

```
this._etsyService.getProd().subscribe(product => {
        this.product = product[0];
    });
```

And in your template

```
{{ product.name }}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this was the issue with that particular json.  I have a similar issue with a different API that's returning json like this:

{ "response": { "version": "0.1", "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html", "features": { "conditions": 1 } }, "current_observation": { "image": { "url": "http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png", "title": "Weather Underground"

If I try to specify {{ product.title }} nothing shows.  I guess I just don't have enough experience parsing json data, so I'm running into these issues.

Comment: I believe this is not all of the json. If you can edit the question and add your new json as update i can take a clear look.

Comment: Ah okay, I got it now.  this.product = product['current_observation']['image'];   works. In this case, within the .subscribe function, I would have to add multiple variables such as: this.product, this.otherinfo, this.etc.. in order to access different parts of that json return.  I'm just curious if there's a way to do that within the view.

Comment: Set this.product = product; and access to product.current_observation.image, product.etc in the template. All the properties returned from the json will be available in the view in this way.

Comment: Wow man.. I tried that last night, I swear! (I was drinking, though) and it would not work.  Now it does.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as answer if it's solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

For that you could use `?.` operator whenever you deal with async call as shown below,

```
{{product?.name})
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in @cuongngo comment, `*ngIf="product"` on a parent container is a relatively simple fix.

Something like this should also work...

```
{{ (product | async).name }}
```